# Laravel - Return associated models to json

Tags: json, laravel, associations

I have two models, `Threads` and `Leads`.

I'm trying to return the lead with the threads as a JSON object but all I am getting is a `leads` field that is null.

Threads Model;

```
public function leads()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Leads');
}
```

Leads Model;

```
public function threads()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Threads');
}
```

ThreadsController;

```
public function getLead($id=null)
{
    $thread = Threads::thread($id)->with('leads')->get();

    return Response::json($thread)->setCallback(Input::get('callback'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `with()`, try to `load()` them:

```
$thread = Threads::thread($id)->load('leads')->get();
```

Also, a note on your namings: your `Threads` model's `leads()` function should be called `lead()` because a `Thread` got only one `Lead` (thats why you used `belongsTo()`), but this is only for readibility.